# PhpExcel определить кол-во листов

Tags: phpexcel, php

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
//есть чудесная команда, обращающаяся к листу
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

//есть список листов
$objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
```

Но никак не могу найти в мануале кол-во листов. Есть ли такая команда? Не ну count по массиву с названиями листов тоже можно сделать, но все же это не то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getSheetCount(); пробовали?
```

Comment: Оно. жаль с ходу в справке не нашел. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`$objPHPExcel->getSheetCount()` вернет количество страниц, начиная с 0.